# EWS and TLS 1.2 - having issues connecting automatically

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

One of our clients has upgraded to Tls 1.2.

However, the `ExchangeService` client has problems connecting to it, unless I add the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This likely won't work for all of our clients.  Is there a way to make it detect which one to use automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple supported protocols by doing something like this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
    SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Using this sample of code, you allow all security protocols (supported by .NET).